# JavaScript perform some action on browsers tab close and on borwser close

Tags: javascript

I need to close user chat session on browsers tab close and browser close in JavaScript.

For Example: if the user did not close his/her chat and close the browser tab or the browser itself then his/her chat session should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    // Ajax request to update db here
}
```